# Экспресс-панель браузеров

Tags: javascript, html

Как реализовать автоматическое добавление сайта в экспресс-панель браузеров? Вышло только через API Табло яндекса.  Но для этого нужен виджет "Визуальные закладки" [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В общем случае никак, т. к. это "отличительные фишки" конкретных браузеров. Разве что найдёте вендор-специфичные API для каждого.